# Java FX showing a LoadingScreen while code and other objects are running/drawn

Tags: javafx

So I want to display a Loading Screen(simple Stackpane with an ProgressIndicator on top of a blur etc..) over my Desktop Application while another Screen is loading data from the database and drawing itself. Up until now I used a Task in a new Thread to "split" my loading animation running in the FX thread from the logic in the background, problem is this time logic and drawing objects on the screen in the bakckground are heavily intervowen and I cannot split them without stupenduous amount of work.

So I found out about AnimationTimer, which apparently is called on every frame and sends a pulse which causes an equivalent to a repaint() in Swing. And so I tried to use it thus:

```
public void showApplicationScreen(){
    public void addAndShowTransporterStatus() {
        AnimationTimer at = new AnimationTimer() {
            int i;
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                i++;
                LOG.info(i);  //testing to see frames per second
            }
        };
    at.start();
    showLoadingIndicator(true);
    loadDataFromDBandDrawObjects();
    showLoadingIndicator(false);
    at.stop();
}
```

Is there some kind of trick to it that I am missing? Or some other (simple) way?

I cant believe something so simple is so complicated to do. Gotta say I wish every Node had a `repaintAtIntervall(double timespan)` method that would suspend everything else the application is doing atm and repaint itself before continuing with  the normal flow. Might not be pretty but it sure as hell would be useful.

Comment: "problem is this time logic and drawing objects on the screen in the bakckground are heavily intervowen". Maybe that is not a very good design?

Comment: Its old code from single thread times. I think. Or someone didnt know better and wrote this. I dont know, but what I know is that changing it now would take a very long time and deadline is not far.

Comment: Note that the animation timer does not "send a pulse". The pulses are generated as part of the operation of the toolkit: if you create and start an animation timer its `handle(..)` method is simply executed once for each pulse. But `AnimationTimer` is not intended for this use case (as i understand your question, anyway); it is more designed as a hook into the rendering loop that can be used for simulations and games. See eg http://asipofjava.blogspot.com/2014/05/game-loops-and-applying-them-to-javafx.html?m=0

Comment: For "repaint at interval" functionality, just use a `Timeline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't need an `AnimationTimer` for something like this. If you are doing the initial loading in a background thread, use a `Task`. Show a loading screen and hide it in the task's `onSucceeded` handler. You can create node instances in a background thread as long as they are not part of the scene graph, so while it's not a particularly good design, you can do something like:

```
Task<Parent> createMainScene = new Task<Parent>() {
    @Override
    public Parent call() {
        Parent root = ... ;
        // load data etc., create structure below root
        // call updateMessage(...) to update a status message if needed
        // call updateProgress(...) to update the progress if needed
        // ...
        return root ;
    }
};

ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
pBar.progressProperty().bind(createMainScene.progressProperty());
Label statusLabel = new Label();
statusLabel.textProperty().bind(createMainScene.messageProperty());
VBox root = new VBox(5, statusLabel, pBar);
Stage loadingStage = new Stage(new Scene(root));
loadingStage.show();

createMainScene.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createMainScene.getValue()));
    primaryStage.show();
    loadingStage.hide();
});

new Thread(createMainScene).start();
```

A better (more properly-separated) design would be to have the task just load the application data and process it, and return an object encapsulating the data. Then in the `onSucceeded` handler you would create the UI from the data (which should not take a long time). However, it sounds like you cannot do that with the current code with which you're working.

Comment: Problem is the Nodes are part of the SceneGraph and I get an "not part of an FX-Thread" exception or something like that. However your code gave me an idea. What if I just start a new Stage for the Loading Screen with its own FXThread? If I make it borderless and maybe I can even make it see-trough it shouldnt even be very noticable. The ugliest of solutions but it might just work. My loading Screen is just a simple rotating circle anyway. I dont need any binding to values.

Comment: You can't start your own FX thread. It's the same as swing: it's a single threaded toolkit. "Live" UI components must be updated on the UI thread. Probably you should clarify your question, ideally with a complete minimal example that makes the issue clear.

Comment: I am just loading Data to TransportObjects(name, icon etc..) from the DB and then create a Node in which it is displayed on the screen. So when Its done I have Boxes with various Transport vehicles that have names and images, showing on the screen that I can click on and it opens up Details. All that takes about 7 seconds or so during which I want the user to see a loading screen not the frozen application. So while the app is loading necesary Data from the DB and drawing those Boxes I want my Loading Sreen with the spinning circle to be shown.

Comment: That sounds like you can just accomplish it with a `Task`. The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) have many usage examples. Just load them from the DB in the task and return a collection of them, and in the `onSucceeded` handler create the nodes from them and display. Not sure where your "repaintAtInterval" functionality would be needed at all for that. Note that the time is (almost certainly) all taken up by loading them from the DB; it is not taken up by drawing them.

Comment: Well my example was a bit simplified but yeah you are right a task would work and it was my initial approach until I kind of got lost in the hundreds of lines of code across tens of classes trying to find the DB loading occurences. "repaintAtInterval" would be useful in supporting my laziness I suppose. Oh well there is no helping it, I will have to fight my inner "Schweinehund" as we say and just do it, if there is no quick and dirty way. Thanks for putting up with me tough, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out it was a good thing to check the code, took long but I found out that I am creating the details for every Transport Box on initialization of the screeen. No wonder it took so long, now I create the Details when I actually click on a Box, and turns out I dont even need a loading screen anymore cause the screen shows up instantly.